# How to add 'top' and 'bottom' directions with leaflet marker label

Tags: leaflet, labeling

I need to add a label to marker from bottom. But there are no any value to add for direction option in bindLabel method.

```
 var marker = L.marker([ latitude, longitude ], {
         icon : iconInfo,
         iconAnchor: [10, 10],
         labelAnchor: [6, 0]
     }).bindLabel(displayingText, {
         direction: 'right',
         noHide : true
     }).addTo(leaf_map);
```

It only have `right|left|auto` options only. 
How can I achieve this with leaflet marker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `bindLabel` from the plugin [Leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) is deprecated but its functionality was included in Leaflet core from version 1.0 using [tooltip](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#tooltip).

This should work within your code:

```
var marker = L.marker([ latitude, longitude ], {
         icon : iconInfo,
         iconAnchor: [10, 10],
         labelAnchor: [6, 0]
     }).bindTooltip(displayingText, {
         direction: 'bottom',
         permanent : true
     }).addTo(leaf_map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the offset option of [leaflet.Label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label)

> offset: Position offset from the marker icon's labelAnchor